# Permissions issue with deployed Laravel app on Google Cloud

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, php-7.2

[Just deployed an app on google cloud. runtime is php72 and env is standard. I've already changed my storage folder to 755 but I still get an error. Not sure which file to change it's permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tsEs.png)

Comment: The error is quite clear. "Read-only file system", this is not a permissions problem.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Google's docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security#filesystem), the filesystem is read-only (so chmod isn't gonna do a thing) except in certain cases, and `/srv` isn't one of them.